# Plot times of day in Matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working with lists, which contain the timestamps of different events as a string. For example, a list would be:

```py
a = ['08:50:00', '08:50:00', '10:05:00', '10:30:00', '10:30:00', '10:46:00', '10:50:00', '10:52:00', '11:00:00', '11:10:00', '11:10:00', '12:10:00', '12:20:00', '15:50:00', '16:20:00', '16:30:00']
```

All of its components are `str`s, not datetime types. I would like to be able to plot them to see if there's any time in the day in which events occurs most frequently.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with the [Matplotlib Tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html) or browse the [Gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html) - I'm sure you will start to get ideas for solving your problem. You probably need to start with converting your strings to datetime objects. Do some searching on SO you'll probably find plenty of relavent examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problems sounds pretty much like you are looking for a histogram.

In the code I converted your stuff to datetime format and extracted the hours. Afterwards use the histogram function from matplotlib.

Of course you can make the matplotlib figure a lot nicer, but I hope you get the point.

Just a hint: I found all these things in the brilliant documentation of matplotlib and here on stackoverflow. Hope this helps:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = ['08:50:00', '08:50:00', '10:05:00', '10:30:00', '10:30:00', '10:46:00', '10:50:00', '10:52:00', '11:00:00', '11:10:00', '11:10:00', '12:10:00', '12:20:00', '15:50:00', '16:20:00', '16:30:00']

# Convert to datetime format and get hours
hours_list = [dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%H:%M:%S').hour for date in a]

# Plot histogram from 0h to 24h
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(hours_list, 12)
plt.xlabel('Hours')
plt.ylabel('Occurences')
plt.title('Events')
plt.axis([0, 24, 0, n.max()])
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```